# What firewall ports should be opened for central management server

Tags: sql-server-2008, central-management-server

Within my environment we currently have a MSSQL installation which serves as the Master in a [Multiserver Agent environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-multiserver-environment) (MSX). Due to this server being within a tightly controlled network the necessary ports for MSX functionality have not been opened.

As shown in the image, when I try to enlist a target (TSX) to the master (MSX) I am given an error that the RFC server is not available, I am also unable to deploy multi-server jobs to targets.

What ports should I request to be opened from targets to the master and vice versa?

[image]

Comment: Look which ports are listened by CMS... 6400 by default AFAIR.

Comment: @akina Do you recommend a way of seeing which ports are listening? The documentation is very limited in this regard.

Comment: Yes. Or look at CMS settings - service port may be settable...

Comment: CMS is a slightly different feature. This is about Multi-server job administration. The master server is considered the MSX and the target is the TSX. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26222524/1948808

Comment: @AMtwo thanks for the link. Unfortunately the answer posted on that link remains unanswered. I know that for sure RPC endpoint mapper port 135 needs to be opened, but there is also a range of dynamic ports that RPC uses. This link seems to suggest a range of ports: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fort_sql/2012/07/03/sql-server-ports/

Answer (score 1):

When you attempt to enlist the Target (TSX) to the Master (MSX), the step that is failing is "Make sure the Agent service for '{MSX Server}' is running." This step simply checks to see that the SQL Server Agent is running on the MSX Server.

You can instead try to use `msdb.dbo.sp_msx_enlist` ([documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-msx-enlist-transact-sql)), which is run on the TSX to enlist it on the MSX. This may provide a more helpful error message, or it may even succeed.

If it succeeds, you can query `msdb.dbo.systargetservers` on the MSX to confirm that the server has been successfully enrolled, and is polling for instructions to download. Next, you can poll `msdb.dbo.sysdownloadlist` to see those instructions, and see if they are being consumed correctly by the TSX. There is an `error_message` column which should include download errors. Note, errors being logged here would be dependent on the TSX successfully connecting to the MSX--so your TSX would need to be able to connect to the MSX's DB Engine port (1433 by default) in order to even write the error messages.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. Port 1433 is open, I am able to enlist using the stored procedure and see the server in the systargerservers table. When querying the sysdownloadlist, I see the commands that are trying to be sent to the target, but the date_downloaded remains empty / status remains 0.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to open the following ports:

1. the TCP port the "target" server is listening on, you can check that on the target server: `select * from sys.dm_tcp_listener_states`
2. for the adding, it uses RPC (remote procedure call): open up ports : TCP & UDP : 139
3. if you want to take SMB for backups (can but dislike) : TCP & UDP: 445
4. check that the registery key for the instance sql agent on the target is set to 0 key to check: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\ Your instance\SQLServerAgent\MsxEncryptChannelOptions
5. If your target is a higher version than the MSX create the service account user of the target on the Master MSX prior to adding.
   check by: `select * from sys.dm_server_services` on the target server.
   Grant that found service account the role memberschip "targetserverrole" in the MSDB on the master MSX.

Comment: Just to add onto this, I've encountered RPC unavailability errors with drops on port 135 too.